# How can I use free transform to rotate an picture while keeping resolution

Tags: resolution, transform, pixlr

I'm trying to rotate several images of artwork without losing resolution for some banner artwork.  Every time I save the image after using free transform to rotate it's a bigger file size but the resolution isn't good enough quality for print.

I'm using [Pixlr Editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/) (A simpler, less powerful, web based software like Photoshop)

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to GDSE, your question is missing the tag of the application you use to edit your work.

Comment: You are asking about losing image quality but also about the file size increases. Which of these is the actual issue?

Comment: See [This answer for why your image might be increasing in size.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/84318)

Comment: Hi Ovaryraptor!  The issue is my images are not high enough resolution for the banner once I've rotated and saved them.  However, I'm also only allowed 10mg of uploads for the banner so size does matter!  I should probably also mention that I've had to resize the canvas to use free transform to rotate the square images which obviously would add to the size of the output file.

Comment: Hi Danielillo and Overyraptor, I've been working on the images for three days now and have sort of reached the end.  I think I'll have to leave the images square which will not have as much impact on the banner but I'm running out of time to submit the work for my banner. Thanks for your interest in my question.  I'll be back no doubt!

Comment: Could be an issue with the application. I don't think what you're describing should happen.

Comment: Hi Joonas, thank you , yes you are correct.  I have since found out that Pxl Editor only saves up to 170 dpi. I didn't realise it was designed specifically for web not print based artwork.

Answer (score -1):

On that application, you can not.

Use a vector based program like Corel Draw or Illustrator.

If you stretch, squish and squash a photo inside them the file's size will be constant. With embedded and with linked images as well (in programs like InDesign)

When you increase the size of the image, the image's size will remain intact, but the catch is that you are actually squishing and squashing the print resolution of the file in an inverse proportion.

If you increase the image's size by 2, you reduce the print resolution by 2. There is no way around. It is just the way things work.

You need to start with a good image size from the start that will be able to withstand your manipulation.

Some free applications that you can use are Inkscape, Scribus and Gravit designer.